# How to open files in a directory starting from a specific file

Tags: python, file

In order to open **all** the files in a specific directory (`path`). I use the following code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):  # For each file inside path              
     with open(path + filename, 'r') as xml_file:
          #Do some stuff
```

However, I want to read the files in the directory starting from a specific position. For instance, if the directory contains the files `f1.xml, f2.xml, f3.xml, ... ,f10.xml` in this order, how can I read all the files starting from `f3.xml` (and ignore `f1.xml` and `f2.xml`) ?

Comment: `os.listdir` returns a list of filenames. you can sort lists using `.sort()`. you can search an item in a list and get it's index using `some_list.index("some value")`. you can slice a list to start from a specific index like `for item in some_list[5:]`. Try if that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforward way

```
import os

keep = False
first = 'f3.xml'

for filename in os.listdir(path):  # For each file inside path
     keep = keep or filename == first
     if keep:
         with open(path + filename, 'r') as xml_file:
             #Do some stuff
```